# Ads suspended due to malicious software

Tags: google-adsense, hacked-site, malicious

All the ads for my website have been disapproved last week due to malicious (third party) software. I checked the whole website and noticed the third party script on the header section related to *Localmed*. But I have removed all scripts and scanned the whole site again and found no malware now.

But my ads are still being disapproved again and again. Can you please help me as I am losing my business due to this reason.

I have also attached the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Verify that's it's clean in Google's Search Console first. Then you'll need to resubmit it for review - see the answer in the linked question. There's not much else we can tell you than to keep trying.

Comment: It's clean in the Google search console, kindly refer to the attached screenshots in above comment. I have checked through various online tools like virustotal, sucuri, etc and received no such issues. But still Google ads are not approving.

Comment: You'll need to [request a review](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7003627?hl=en) - there's nothing more we can advise since we don't have any control over AdSense's decisions.

Comment: I am not talking about Adsense, I am talking about the Google Ads only

Comment: Same thing, contact [Google Ads](https://ads.google.com/intl/en_hk/home/contact-us/) and ask for a review. There's nothing we can do for you here.